# Php MYadmin mysql error ( Need to run query and ignore errors )

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mysql

I have patches in .sql format.I copied the Query's and pasted it in phpmy admin and  while execution , My PC rebooted due to some power fault. Now half of those SQL statements are executed and half are not , when i try to run those again i get Duplicated entry , table errors etc.

> Is there a way to execute .sql file while ignoring the errors which
>   are encountered.

Some one told me it could be done through the mysql prompt ? Any ideas?

Comment: Mysql provide insert ignore option but this applied on single query as you are running sql file, probably you dont want to edit each query. You can truncate your table, if you can! and run again your sql file.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary - No i cannot truncate it. Some other option please. Isnt a mysql prompt syntax to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql`'s [`--force` option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_force):

> ```
> --force, -f
> ```
>
> Continue even if an SQL error occurs.